# Как вставлять записи в таблицу (foreign) | laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

Есть таблица, которая связана с другой с помощью foreign. Если я пытаюсь вставить в неё данные, то получаю ошибку:

```
> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test-laravel`.`posts`, CONSTRAINT `posts_ndepart_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`ndepart`) REFERENCES `departments` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `posts` (`users_id`, `ndepart`) values (2,13, 16)) at C:\Users\Николай\Documents\test-laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:665
    661|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    662|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    663|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    664|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 665|             throw new QueryException(
    666|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    667|             );
    668|         }
    669|
  Exception trace:
  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test-laravel`.`posts`, CONSTRAINT `posts_ndepart_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`ndepart`) REFERENCES `departments` (`id`))")
      C:\Users\Николай\Documents\test-laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:459
  2   PDOStatement::execute()
      C:\Users\Николай\Documents\test-laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:459
 Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Что делать, и как правильно вставлять данные в такую таблицу?

Comment: Проверьте fillable у модели - есть ли там ndepart

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что в модели необходимо заполнить два поля, а значений приходит три: "into `posts` (`users_id`, `ndepart`) values (2,13, 16)"?

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, миграции и способ обновления модели

Comment: 2,13 - строка.!

Comment: @PRO CODE: а должно быть bigInteger? Стало быть ошибка в коде обновления модели.

Comment: Нет, должно быть string, я не использую модель, какой код обновления модели?

Comment: Каким образом Вы пытаетесь вставить данные в таблицу posts?  Покажите код, который я просил.

Comment: class PostsSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     * Функция добавляет пользователей в отделы
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        for($i = 1; $i <= 16; $i++)
        {
            DB::table('posts')->insert([
                'users_id' => rand(1,8) . ',' . rand(9, 16),
                'ndepart' => $i,
            ]);
        }
    }
}

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101313/discussion-between-yakoffka-and-pro-code).